# Missing Django core translations

Tags: django, django-i18n

I am trying to translate django contrib strings which for my language are untranslated in the original .po file. When I add them to my own .po file and translate them, the system works fine. The problem comes every time I use the makemessages command, since the generator interprets that those text strings have been deleted and comments them in the .po file. Can I hand generate a file that contains the translations and is not affected by the makemessages command? On the other hand, is it possible to tell him not to comment on the deleted lines?

Comment: What are the missing translations ?

Comment: /django/contrib/auth/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po. Sorry, It is in contrib, not core.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective would be probably to contribute directly to the Django project to provide those translations so they are included in the next version!

See "[Localizing Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/localizing/)" for details.